# Can I get a tree-structure from a self-referenced (hierarchical) table?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, hierarchy

Given a hierarchical table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[btree]
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
, parent_id INT REFERENCES [dbo].[btree] ([id])
, name NVARCHAR(20)
);
```

I would like to obtain the whole tree structure.

For instance, using this data:

```
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (1, null, '1 Root');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (2,    1, '1.1 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (3,    1, '1.2 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (4,    2, '1.1.1 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (5,    2, '1.1.2 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (6,    3, '1.2.1 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (7,    3, '1.2.2 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (8,    4, '1.1.1.1 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (9,    4, '1.1.1.2 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (10,   5, '1.1.2.1 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (11,   5, '1.1.1.2 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (12,   6, '1.2.1.1 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (13,   6, '1.2.1.2 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (14,   7, '1.2.2.1 Items');
```

I would like to obtain:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | parent_id | description         |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |    NULL   | 1 Root              |
|  2 |     1     |   1.1 Group         |
|  4 |     2     |     1.1.1 Group     |
|  8 |     4     |       1.1.1.1 Items |
|  9 |     4     |       1.1.1.2 Items |
|  5 |     2     |     1.1.2 Group     |
| 10 |     5     |       1.1.2.1 Items |
| 11 |     5     |       1.1.2.2 Items |
|  3 |     1     |   1.2 Group         |
|  6 |     3     |     1.2.1 Group     |
| 12 |     6     |       1.2.1.1 Items |
| 13 |     6     |       1.2.1.2 Items |
|  7 |     3     |     1.2.2 Group     |
| 14 |     7     |       1.2.2.1 Items |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

I'm fetching records using a recursive query like this:

```
;WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT c1.id, c1.parent_id, c1.name, [level] = 1
    FROM dbo.[btree] c1
    WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.id, c2.parent_id, c2.name, [level] = tree.[level] + 1
    FROM dbo.[btree] c2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parent_id
)
SELECT tree.level, tree.id, parent_id, REPLICATE('  ', tree.level - 1) + tree.name AS description
FROM tree
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

And this is the current result:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | parent_id | description         |
|  1 |    NULL   | 1 Root              |
|  2 |     1     |   1.1 Group         |
|  3 |     1     |   1.2 Group         |
|  6 |     3     |     1.2.1 Group     |
|  7 |     3     |     1.2.2 Group     |
| 14 |     7     |       1.2.2.1 Items |
| 12 |     6     |       1.2.1.1 Items |
| 13 |     6     |       1.2.1.2 Items |
|  4 |     2     |     1.1.1 Group     |
|  5 |     2     |     1.1.2 Group     |
| 10 |     5     |       1.1.2.1 Items |
| 11 |     5     |       1.1.1.2 Items |
|  8 |     4     |       1.1.1.1 Items |
|  9 |     4     |       1.1.1.2 Items |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

I can't figure out how to order it by levels.

Is there a way to set a rank for each sub-level?

I've set up a <kbd>[**Rextester**](http://rextester.com/ZKNQKQ76303)</kbd>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a "path" field and sort by that similar to a file path. As ypercube mentioned, the sorting is overly simplistic in this example and just happens to work but for simplicity's sake I'll leave as is. Most of the time when I use this pattern I sort by name rather than ID anyway.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[btree]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[btree];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[btree]
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
, parent_id INT REFERENCES [dbo].[btree] ([id])
, name NVARCHAR(20)
);
GO

INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (1, null, '1 Root');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (2,    1, '1.1 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (3,    1, '1.2 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (4,    2, '1.1.1 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (5,    2, '1.1.2 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (6,    3, '1.2.1 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (7,    3, '1.2.2 Group');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (8,    4, '1.1.1.1 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (9,    4, '1.1.1.2 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (10,   5, '1.1.2.1 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (11,   5, '1.1.2.2 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (12,   6, '1.2.1.1 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (13,   6, '1.2.1.2 Items');
INSERT INTO [btree] VALUES (14,   7, '1.2.2.1 Items');

;WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT c1.id, c1.parent_id, c1.name, [level] = 1, path = cast('root' as varchar(100))
    FROM dbo.[btree] c1
    WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.id, c2.parent_id, c2.name, [level] = tree.[level] + 1, 
           Path = Cast(tree.path+'/'+right('000000000' + cast(c2.id as varchar(10)),10) as varchar(100))
    FROM dbo.[btree] c2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parent_id
)
SELECT tree.path, tree.id, parent_id, REPLICATE('  ', tree.level - 1) + tree.name AS description
FROM tree
Order by path
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

Here a [rextester](http://rextester.com/BCEL76331)

Comment: It's the right idea but in the path expression should have `c2.id` replaced with a row_number and padded on the left so all the parts have equal length. Otherwise, it won't work for all data. Just replace 2 with 55 in  the data and the order changes

Comment: Totally agree. I'm on mobile and wanted to win the race to the answer :) Actually I'd use the "name" field in the path generally. That's usually my use case.

Comment: I'm probably wrong about the row number (not needed) but the padding is. +1 (If we do use row_number, the path will reconstruct the first part of name!)

Comment: I've edited the `Path` with a small correction, to add padding.

Comment: I like a lot this solution, but I wonder what should be path length when `id` raise more than 6 digits. I don't expect more than 5 levels

Comment: As I told to @ypercubeᵀᴹ, name cannot be used. I've numbered it for the sake of the example.

Comment: I usually use double my expected path length if there's any doubt as to max depth. Also you can reduce the zero padding if you know the maximum order of magnitude of the ID/row_number.

Answer (score 4):

Cheating, just a bit ;) Look ma, no recursion!

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/AHH54898)

```
SELECT btree.*        -- , a,b,c,d     -- uncomment to see the parts
FROM btree 
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT rlc = REVERSE(LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)-1))) AS r
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT a = CAST(REVERSE(PARSENAME(r.rlc, 1)) AS int),
             b = CAST(REVERSE(PARSENAME(r.rlc, 2)) AS int),
             c = CAST(REVERSE(PARSENAME(r.rlc, 3)) AS int),
             d = CAST(REVERSE(PARSENAME(r.rlc, 4)) AS int)
    ) AS p 
ORDER BY a, b, c, d ;
```

Of course the above is rather limited. It works only under the assumptions:

- the `name` column has stored (in the first part) the actual "path".
- the depth of the tree is maximum 4 (so the path has up to 4 parts).
- the `CAST .. AS int` is needed only if the parts are numbers.

Explanation: The code works by using the function [`PARSENAME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) which has the main purpose of splitting an object name into its 4 parts:

```
Server.Database.Schema.Object
  |        |       |      |
 4th      3rd     2nd    1st
```

Note that the order is reverse. As an example, `PARSENAME('dbo.btree', 2)` will give us `'dbo'` as a result.With 3, we'll get NULL (that's why the `REVERSE()` is used twice in the code. Otherwise we'd get the nulls in the beginning. The `'1.2'` would be parsed into `null, null, 1, 2` while we want `1, 2, null, null`.)

---

Conclusion: after all that, I should add that the answer by Bob Campbel is the way to go as it is more general and produces (in the "path" column in the result) the path hierarchy, which can then be used for the `ORDER BY`.

Other options you may consider - if the size of the table grows big and the recursive solution becomes slow - is to actually store the path in a separate column (in a format that is good for ordering, i.e. with padding) or to use the provided [`HierarchyID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) type which is exactly for this use case, hierarchical data.

Comment: :) It's really awesome! Unfortunately `name` cannot be used in this case. It will take me all night long to decipher it, could I have some explanation?

Comment: So, the "name" column does not have the data you provided in the example? Pity.

Comment: No, I've used it as example, just to remark there are some levels.

Comment: In real life, are pieces inside a plastic bags, inside a carton box, inside a pallets, inside an expedition order.

Comment: @Mcnets in the (unlikely) case that the `name` does store a path (with text), like `'order173.palletA27.box9'.bag3A`, you could still use the code (just remove the casts to int). In any case, the query by BenCambell  is the way to go in general.

Comment: I think I've got the idea. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It's a cute and fun exploit. I like clever a lot. Have an upvote. Just out of curiosity is there a less-bizarre way of doing this in SQL Server? In PostgreSQL we could do the same thing by using `string_to_array()` which would make a bit more sense, work on more than four levels, and not require the literal `.`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll yes, the hierarchyid type. I was just adding a last paragraph about other options with link.

Comment: The string_to_array() would be used in Postgres I guess as an improvement of the recursive method. It's not needed really unless for elegance or performance. The ltree extension is similar to SQL Server's hierarchyid and provides many functions that are more simple to use than recursive queries.

Comment: Hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ, I'm reading about HierarchyID, and all examples starts from a root level. In my case, it works in the opposite side, my first record is always an orphan child.  Does it mean that I must update all descendant records, every time a new parent is assigned?

Comment: An orphan child? What that would be in the data you provided?

Comment: Talking with expedition boys, there is no problem I can start on root level. I'm sorry.