# List parent then nested child items in a single table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

With the following SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE Software (
    ID INT,
    name VARCHAR(150),
    ParentID INT );

INSERT INTO Software VALUES (1,'Main Product',NULL); 
INSERT INTO Software VALUES (2,'Next Main Product',NULL); 
INSERT INTO Software VALUES (3,'Addon Product',1); 
INSERT INTO Software VALUES (4,'Addon Product',1); 
INSERT INTO Software VALUES (5,'Sub-Addon Product',3);
```

I need to create a query that will sort the data by picking the first Main Product, then finding any addon products where the parent ID matches the ID of the parent, then seeing if that addon-product has any sub-addon products.

The Query I've tried based on one of the recommendations is

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM Software
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL)
SELECT 
    Software.ID,
    Software.name
FROM Software
INNER JOIN x ON x.ID=Software.ParentID OR x.ID = Software.ID
```

The output however misses the sub-addon product shown below:

```
/---------------------
| ID  | Name
| 1   | Main Product
| 3   |   Addon Product
| 4   |   Addon Product
| 2   | Main Product
\----------------------
```

What I need is this where the sub-addon is added

```
/---------------------
| ID  | Name
| 1   | Main Product
| 3   |   Addon Product
| 5   |     Sub-Addon Product
| 4   |   Addon Product
| 2   | Next Main Product
\----------------------
```

Comment: You're looking for a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which is pretty well documented.

Comment: I think this question could solve your problem. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160924/can-i-get-a-tree-structure-from-a-self-referenced-hierarchical-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as you want to obtain all records where `parent_id is null`, I'd suggest to use an inline udf function.

> ```
> -- Inline UDF function
> CREATE FUNCTION fnTree(@ID int)
> RETURNS table AS
> RETURN
> (
>     WITH tree AS
>     (
>       SELECT c1.id, c1.parent_id, c1.name, [level] = 1, path = cast(c1.id as varchar(100))
>       FROM dbo.[software] c1
>       WHERE c1.id = @ID
>       UNION ALL
>       SELECT c2.id, c2.parent_id, c2.name, [level] = tree.[level] + 1, Path=Cast(tree.path+'/'+cast(c2.id as varchar(10)) as varchar(100))
>       FROM dbo.[software] c2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parent_id
>     )
>     SELECT tree.path, tree.id, parent_id, REPLICATE('  ', tree.level - 1) + tree.name as name
>     FROM tree
> );
> GO
> ```

Then you can CROSS APPLY this function with all records where `parent_id is null`
Take care when using a recursive function, you should set `OPTION (MAXRECURSION XXX)` just to ensure it can hold all returned records.

> ```
> SELECT      f.id, f.name, f.parent_id, f.path
> FROM        software
> CROSS APPLY fnTree(software.id) f
> WHERE       software.parent_id IS NULL
> ORDER BY    f.path
> OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name                  | parent_id | path 
> -: | :-------------------- | --------: | :----
>  1 | Main Product          |      null | 1    
>  3 |   Addon Product       |         1 | 1/3  
>  5 |     Sub-Addon Product |         3 | 1/3/5
>  4 |   Addon Product       |         1 | 1/4  
>  2 | Next Main Product     |      null | 2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b32955f32d732a1e1cea0372c6e274ed)*