# Is it possible to upsert into a self-referencing table with a single statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, self-join

If I have a table `A`, like so:

```
A {
 id SERIAL
 title TEXT
 ...
 parentId INT references A.id via a foreign key constraint
}
```

I am pulling data from a source table - `A_SOURCE` - where there isn't a `parentId` column. Instead there is a `parentTitle` column. So the source table looks something like this:

```
A_SOURCE {
  title TEXT
  parentTitle TEXT
}
```

I started writing an upsert statement to insert into table `A` via a selection from table `A_SOURCE` before I realized that I can't easily resolve the `parentTitle` column in the source to a `parentId` in the target.

Since I can't be sure that the parent will have been inserted at the time the child being processed, a join or a subquery could return no results.

My upsert statement is looking something like this:

```
with source as (
  select
   title
   parentTitle
  from A_SOURCE 
)

insert into A
select
title
... I don't think I can resolve to parentId here?
from source
on concflict ...;
```

I know that I can run two separate statements:

1. insert with `null` as parentId
2. Then update the parentId fields in the second statement

But is it possible to do this in a single query?

Comment: What do you want to do if the parent title is not in the table? Insert 2 rows, one for the parent and another for the child?

Comment: yes - there are N rows in the source table, some of these N rows have a non-null `parentTitle` that is the same as a title in another row, and some have a parentTitle that is NULL

Comment: Sorry I have to delete my answer. Now I understand better your problem when you say A_SOURCE is coming from CSV file, I see the ids still not exists, as you are using the sequence to generate them... You will need two queries to do the insert effectively. I have a similar case in some system here...

Comment: I thought it was worth asking in case there was a way that I could have an `insert` statement as a subquery or something.

Comment: Please, have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Would `DEFERRED` foreign constraint work for you?

Comment: Would it be cheating the wrap the two queries into a function (or an anonymous DO block), which can then be invoked with one query?

Comment: @jjanes - no. but that sounds like i would have to write more sql......

Comment: @a1ex07 - i didn't know of that. however from a quick search i'm not sure how that would help

Comment: @McNets - i tried to be succinct as possible, do you mean that there needs to be working examples?

Comment: It's the best way to avoid comments and get the most accurate answer. There are some fiddles that help users to test and post an answer. Have a look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160924/can-i-get-a-tree-structure-from-a-self-referenced-hierarchical-table)

Comment: That makes sense - I'll do that in the future @McNets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare the values to insert with a recursive CTE that pre-calculates the `id`s and defines an order. Then insert it in that order:

```
WITH RECURSIVE a_sort AS (
      /* get all entries without a parent (rank 1) */
      SELECT nextval('a_id_seq')::integer AS id,
             title,
             NULL::integer AS parentid,
             parenttitle,
             1 AS rank
      FROM a_source
      WHERE parenttitle IS NULL
   UNION ALL
      /* recursively get all the immediate children and increase rank */
      SELECT nextval('a_id_seq')::integer,
             src.title,
             a_sort.id,
             a_sort.title,
             a_sort.rank + 1
      FROM a_source AS src
         JOIN a_sort ON a_sort.title = src.parenttitle
)
INSERT INTO a
SELECT id,
       title,
       parentid
FROM a_sort
ORDER BY rank;
```

The beauty of the solution is that this uses the sequence behind `a.id` (`a_id_seq` in the example), so the sequence automatically has the correct value after we are done.

This solution assumes that the data in `a_source` are correct, i.e., do not contain cycles.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I don't think that takes into account the currently existing data int `A`, but I can see that wouldn't be too difficult to add? I.e. just start the rank at the current max + 1 in `A` (if I'm reading that correctly)

Comment: No, it does that automatically. I should have added that `a_id_seq` is the serial sequence for `a.id`.

Comment: well it's currently above my understanding. thank you - i will come back to this for a detailed look!